# JS, jQuery Conflict.. help?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, conflict

I am facing issue with a website which is currently on a test location.

The problem is that the site loads incomplete for the first time on any browser and on 2nd time refreshing browser loads it complete.

http://test.whyislam.org

So far i believe its a Jquery conflict issue, any help would be highly appreciated?

Comment: Do you use other javaScript librarys or is jQuery the only one ?

Answer (score 2):

You are loading multiple copies of the library: I counted at least 4 different versions of jQuery. Pick one and remove the rest.

Another possible issue is that scripts aren't set to run on page load. Right at the end:

```
jQuery( '#SlideDeck_877_4' ).slidedeck( ... );
```

You can't be sure that the element has been rendered yet. Change it (and similar code) to:

```
$( document ).load( function() {
    jQuery( '#SlideDeck_877_4' ).slidedeck( ... );
} );
```

Comment: There are only two version of jquery. the other js files just named Jquery. They are not a jquery lib in actual. its because a latest ver is required for slider and other widgets. The old version is required for the 9 boxes in the bottom. If i removed any one of the feature stops working.

Comment: I don't think you can use two versions at the same time. (If you can, I don't know how.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jquery noconflict like this jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: I have used wp_enqueue_script(); isnt it the same thing ?

Comment: No, `wp_enqueue_script()` only makes sure you're not loading the same script twice. It doesn't prevent namespace clashes between different scripts.